# Does an initial condition of "at rest" mean that the velocity is zero, but the acceleration could be nonzero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, acceleration, velocity

I'm solving a differential equation for the relativistic motion of an electron in an electric field. The electron is initially at rest in the uniform field, but I am not sure if the initial condition of being at rest implies both that the initial velocity is zero AND the initial acceleration is zero, or if the velocity is zero but the acceleration is given by
$$a = F/m = Ee/m$$

Comment: If the acceleration were zero, then the velocity would remain zero!

Comment: To solve this differential equation $\dfrac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}=\dfrac{F}{m}$ you must give the initial condition x(0) and D(x)(0), so if the initial velocity is zero the system is initially at rest

Answer (score 2):

Being at rest refers to zero velocity. The moment the electric field is turned on, at t=0, say, the particle will feel a force and hence an acceleration

Answer (score 0):

If the question says in next part that electron accelerate. 
It mean the initial velocity was zero, but acceleration was non zero. 
 If it doesn't, then both are zero.